# Native C++ Exe communicating with C# library

Tags: c#, c++, interop, command-line-interface

I have a following problem:

1. Exe (native C++) implements interfaces Ia and Ib.
2. Dll1 (native C++) has a template class `D<T>`, that implements interface Ic and calls into 3. Exe's Ia's and Ib's implementations.
3. Dll2 (native C++) implements a class E (class E : public `D<E>`)

At run-time happens following: Exe loads Dll2 (several instances) and instantiates E providing it with pointers to its Ia and Ib pointers. Exe "obtains" Ic pointer from Dll2.

Now, I have to allow implementation of Dll2(s) in C# so that Exe can call into Dll2's Ic impl. and Dll2 cann call back to Exe's Ia and Ib i-faces. Further restriction that I don't have to recompile Exe and Dll1 each time when new Dll2 implementation pops up.

Is it possible to implement something like this ?

Comment: Say what? Your description is hard to follow. Get rid of all abbreviations

Comment: I suggest heeding David Heffernan's advice regarding the brittle nature of class inheritance across dlls.  Maintaining binary compatibility in this situation would be tedious.

Comment: Tnx Coda ... the binary compatiblity is a real problem I would face ... I think all I'll try to simplify the problem to consuming C# interface from C++/CLI and vice versa, but w-out COM wrappers. Can anyone give me some hints how I can consume C# interface from C++/CLI dynamically (st like: load C# dll, query i-face and invoke it), w-out COM ?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are going to have to move away from inheritance which is already a rather fragile tool when applied across module boundaries.

I'd point you towards COM. Managed code can expose their interfaces as COM objects and C++ can consume them. And vice versa.